# Postgre insert null in char(3) não funciona

Tags: sql-insert, null

Abaixo o erro e o código que estou rodando
Tem dois campos desta tabela que são definidos como `char(3)`, o campo `uf` e o campo `ufcrm`.

Será que alguém sabe como posso fazer este `insert`?

Erro de SQL:

> ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)

No bloco:

```sql
INSERT INTO medico (crm,nome_med,fone1,fone2,fone3,celular,email,abrev,ufcrm,endereco,bairro,cep,cidade,uf,interno,senha,enviawww,padrao,chavesline,uncp_bak,unimed,uncp,status,cpf,espmed_id,datanasc,bpacns,bpacbo,login,obs_med,idopera_ultacao) values ('SP1913','Fulvius Titanero','11942993020',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Rua Eunice Weaver',NULL,'03333060','Sao Paulo','Sao Paulo',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1) RETURNING id
```

Muito obrigado, vou alterar o "uf" e vou rodar novamente para ver

Abaixo mais alguns erros que eu estava testando aqui

Erro de SQL:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Erro"
LINE 1: Erro de SQL:
        ^
No bloco:

Erro de SQL:

ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)
No bloco:
INSERT INTO medico (ufcrm,uf) 
values ('1', '1') RETURNING id

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Erro"
LINE 1: Erro de SQL:
        ^
No bloco:

Erro de SQL:

ERROR:  value too long for type character(3)
No bloco:
INSERT INTO medico (ufcrm,uf) 
values ('', '') RETURNING id

OK OK OK>
resolvido era o tamnho da uf mesmo

obrigado a todos que ajudaram

Comment: uf está recebendo "Sao Paulo" que tem 9 caracteres, sendo que só suporta 3 caracteres. Neste caso, tem que denifir se São Paulo vai ser 'SP' ou vai ter que aumentar a capacidade do campo para mais caracteres.
O ufcms é a mesma coisa, está inserindo 'NULL' que tem 4 caracteres, num campo que só aceita 3 caracteres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uf` está recebendo "Sao Paulo" que têm **9 caracteres**, sendo que **só suporta 3 caracteres**. Neste caso, tem que definir se "Sao Paulo" vai ser 'SP'(só a sigla do estado) ou vai ter que aumentar a capacidade do campo para mais caracteres (Ex: "Rio Grande do Norte" é o estado brasileiro com maior nome e tem 19 caracteres, essa teria que ser a capacidade máxima deste campo). O `ufcms` é a mesma coisa, está inserindo 'NULL' que tem 4 caracteres, num campo que só aceita 3 caracteres.

Comment: muito obrigado, eu estava com a cabeça e outras coisas e não fiquei atento com o básico, valeu @Edward Ramos